# How to get uid immediate after creating a user in firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a firebase user by

```
  fnCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) : Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    );
  }
```

How I can get the uid of this user?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [API docs for createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword), the promise returned by that function contains a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object.  The user's uid will be in the [uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#uid) field of that object.